# Run background tasks using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class WeatherController < ApplicationController
    def data
        @weather = Weather.all   #show data in data.html.erb
        e = Extractor.new
        e.saveData
    end
end
```

Here is a piece of code in my controller, I use Extractor to get data from webpages and show them on localhost:3000/weather/data.
Now I want to run e.saveData every 10 minutes background, but not refresh my page, could you help me please.

Comment: You can make a task of it and invoke it in your controller's action: `Rake::Task['your_task_name'].invoke(args, for_the, task)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am the one who asked the question.

After comparison, I found that 'rufus-scheduler' is most friendly to use.

See it on https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler#readme

Add it in gemfile, run 'bundle install', then create a file named 'scheduler.rb' in /config/initializer, then put code in it(see the examples), done!

Comment: Wish that this answer could be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You need to introduce background workers

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq

https://github.com/ondrejbartas/sidekiq-cron

https://github.com/Moove-it/sidekiq-scheduler

Comment: And if you want to avoid refreshing the page, you need to reload that data in the "background" using Javascript or something more sophisticated like a WebSocket connection.

Comment: If you are deploying to heroku you can create a rake task and use [Heroku Scheduler](https://addons.heroku.com/scheduler)

Answer (score 0):

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html

The Purpose of Active Job

The main point is to ensure that all Rails apps will have a job infrastructure in place, even if it's in the form of an "immediate runner". We can then have framework features and other gems build on top of that, without having to worry about API differences between various job runners such as Delayed Job and Resque. Picking your queuing backend becomes more of an operational concern, then.